# unity ( Как отправить вводимые значения в InputField в скрипт в виде переменной )

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект и я его копирую нажимая на кнопку, в каждом объекте есть два ввода значений, один (номер объекта ) другой (ввод числа ). Мне нужно что бы клоны и объекты взаимодействовали между собой по номеру, например есть скрипт где значения объектов с номером 2 например складываются между собой. Достаточно думаю такого вопроса: " Что нужно прописать в скрипте что бы  вводимые значения всех клонов отображались в нем в виде переменных?"

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы созданные InputField сразу имели какой то заранее подготовленный текст при создании?

Comment: Или нужно чтобы данные всех текстов InputField где-то хранились?